# why node.js process is killed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I have developed one app in node.js. Recently I noticed when I am doing any changes in my "public" directory of my application, one error is recorded in my log file as follows:

```
error: restarting script because /home/{user}/workspace/{app_folder}/img/{filename}.jpg changed.
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGKILL
error: Forever restarting script for 1 time
Express server listening on port 3000
```

I have already set ***--watchIgnore*** parameter in my forever script file in /etc/init/{app}.config

```
env IGNORE_DIRECTORY="/home/{user}/workspace/{app_folder}/img/**"

exec forever --sourceDir $APPLICATION_DIRECTORY --watchIgnore $IGNORE_DIRECTORY \
      -a -w -l $LOG --minUptime 5000 --spinSleepTime 2000 \
start $APPLICATION_START
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the log shows `{user}` and not your actual user directory. This path looks like it was copied from a user guide, where you were meant to replace those quasi-variables with something.

You use bash environment variables (I assume you're using bash) like this:

`env IGNORE_DIRECTORY="~/workspace/${APPLICATION_DIRECTORY}/img/**"`

It looks like `app_folder` is actually defined for you as `APPLICATION_DIRECTORY`. You can also use `~/` as a shortcut for the current user's home folder.

Comment: {user} is my actual user directory. I am just showing {user} and {app_folder} as an example only.